# .NET Identity Email Confirmed Bool

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, email-confirmation

I want to simply get in my code if the user has his email confirmed or not. Without an async method. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options, if i understood your question correctly:

1. In your database add another 2 columns "EmailConfirmationID" perhaps of type GUID (UniqueIdentifier) and Verified (bit). When the user registers you can insert a new value into EmailConfirmationID send this link to the user (creating a URL) via email. When they click this link within the email you would have the page handle their request and set Verified to true.
2. Have a look at this link http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: this is what I did my friend at the end.. :D .. thank you!